# Deal-Grove Model: How do we arrive at $F_{1}=F_{2}=F_{3}=F=\frac{C^{*}}{\frac{1}{k_{s}}+\frac{X_{ox}}{D}+\frac{1}{h}}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Seems like a trivial question, but I'm confused. What is the step by step way to combine three equations in the Deal-Grove model:

$$F_{1}= h(C^{*}-C_{o})$$
$$F_{2}= \frac{D(C_{o}-C_{i})}{X_{ox}}$$
$$F_{3}= k_{S}C_{i}$$

$$F_{1}=F_{2}=F_{3}=F=\frac{C^{*}}{\frac{1}{k_{s}}+\frac{X_{ox}}{D}+\frac{1}{h}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\text{Given}\qquad F_{1} &= h(C^{*}-C_{o}) \tag{1}\\[1ex]
F_{2} &= \frac{D(C_{o}-C_{i})}{X_{ox}}  \tag{2}\\[1ex]
F_{3} &= k_{S}C_{i} \tag{3}\\
\\
\text{and}\qquad F &=F_{1}=F_{2}=F_{3} \tag{4}\\
\\
F &= h(C^{*}-C_{o}) \tag{from 1&4}\\
C_{o} &= C^{*}-\frac Fh  \tag{5}\\
F &= \frac{D(C_{o}-C_{i})}{X_{ox}}  \tag{from 2&4}\\[1ex]
 &= \frac{D}{X_{ox}}(C^{*}-\frac Fh-C_{i})  \tag{subs. $C_o$ from 5}\\[1ex]
\frac{FX_{ox}}{D} &=C^{*}-\frac Fh-C_{i}\\[1ex]
C_{i} &=C^{*}-F\left(\frac 1h+\frac{X_{ox}}{D}\right) \tag{6}\\[1ex]
F &= k_{S}C_{i} \tag{from 3&4}\\
F &= k_{S}\left[C^{*}-F\left(\frac 1h+\frac{X_{ox}}{D}\right)\right] \quad \tag{subs. $C_i$ from 6}\\[1ex]
\frac 1{k_{S}}F+ F\left(\frac 1h+\frac{X_{ox}}{D}\right) &= C^{*} \\[1ex]
F &=\frac{C^{*}}{\frac{1}{k_{S}}+\frac{X_{ox}}{D}+\frac{1}{h}} \tag {as required}
\end{align}